# Redirect all www.xyz.com to www.xyz.com/wordpress?

Tags: deployment

I have my website working from www.xyz.com/wordpress, but customers should not need to type it all. If they just type www.xyz.com it should take them to www.xyz.com/wordpress.

Comment: you *can* just point your domain to the subdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect `http://www.xyz.com/` to `http://www.xyz.com/wordpress/` add these rules to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?xyz.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress [L]
```

That answers the first part of your question. The rest of it is totally vague to me.

Comment: This works. Thanks. I had to clear the browse cache for it to show up.

Comment: One more quick one, Can I hide the fact that my site is under wordpress folder ?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to enable "cloaking" — which is a very bad practise, frowned upon by everyone (including Google), otherwise I don't really think so. (I suggest you ask that question on StackOverflow where you might get some very good suggestions as well.)